# BlackBerry - How to reference a image located at the res/img folder of a project in a BrowserField for GoogleMap

Tags: java, google-maps, blackberry

I'm showing a google map inside a BrowserField.

This is the relevant code:

```
private String setUpHtmlString(Coordinates coordinates){
        StringBuffer mapString =  new StringBuffer();
        mapString.append("" +
                "<!DOCTYPE html> " +
                "<html>  " +
                "   <head>   " +
                "       <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />   " +
                "       <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>   " +
                "       <script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' type='text/javascript'></script>" +
                "   </head> " +
                "   <body>  " +
                "       <div id='map' style='width: 500px; height: 600px;'></div>  " +
                "       <script type='text/javascript'>    " +
                "           var locations = [      ");

                for (int i = 0; i < _placesStringArray.length; i++) {
                    Address address = ((Place)_hashTablePlaces.get(_placesStringArray[i])).getAddress();
                    mapString.append("['"+address.getDescription()+"', "+address.getLatitude()+", "+address.getLongitude()+", "+i+"]");
                    if(i<_placesStringArray.length - 1)
                        mapString.append(",");
                }

                mapString.append("];");

                mapString.append(
                "           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {      " +
                "               zoom: 15,      " +
                "               center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.290646, -57.584080),      " +
                "               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP    });    " +
                "           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();    " +
                "           var marker, i;    " +
                "           for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {        " +
                "               marker = new google.maps.Marker({        " +
                                    "icon:'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/schools_maps.png', "+
                "                   position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), map: map });      " +
                "               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {        " +
                "                    return function() { " +
                "                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);          " +
                "                        infowindow.open(map, marker);        " +
                "                        }      " +
                "                    })(marker, i));    }  " +
                "        </script>" +
                "    </body>" +
                "</html>");
                return mapString.toString();
    }
```

As you can see, the icon is pointing to an external url, but how should a write the path to a image file inside the img folder
of my app.

[image]

I tried to reference it in many ways, like these:

```
"icon:'local:///assets/images/marker.png'
"icon:'resources/images/marker.png'
```

with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on final directory structure and where is your html file saved. You should use "icon:'img/marker.png'" if `img` and your created html file are in the same directory (and marker.png is saved in img directory).

Comment: thanks Anto, but I don't have a html file since the html is created from a string and passed to the displayContent() method of the BrowserField object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't advice you to hardcode the html inside the .java files, because the code is not readable and also hard to find for future modifications. Inline javascript is already a bad thing, but putting everything into a string in java code is a step beyond in terms of coupling.

**Option #1: the cleanest way**
Instead, you can have a resource html file and load it using a "local:///"  URL, as the BrowserField demo shows:    [Display HTML content from a resource in your application](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Display_HTML_from_a_resource_within_your_app_825672_11.jsp)

In the same directory you can place javascript and css files, as you would do in a regular static web site. So theoretically you could also place image resource files there and reference them from html or js files. The URLs don't need the full path (e.g.: instead of `local:///assets/images/marker.png` you would have `local:///marker.png`).

If you need to insert dynamic content into the html, then you can always insert placeholders into a template html resource file, and then do a string.replace from java code to replace the placeholders with the dynamic fields.

This way you are addressing modifiability and separation of concerns.

**Option #2: the dirty hack**
I've shown you why your code was dirty, but as so many things in life it can still get worse. You can add a new layer of unmodifiability by encoding your image file to a base64 string, and setting a "data://" url to the image in markup or javascript. It might be acceptable for you if the icon is really small and you know in advance you are not going to change it frequently, but be aware base64 strings can grow really large.

**Option #3 (not tested)**
 
This is also kind of a hack. Assuming you can open your image using `Class.getResourceAsStream`, you could instantiate a `ProtocolController` in java code, then call `setNavigationRequestHandler` to set a handler that intercepts the kind of requests you are interested in, and pass the content loaded using `Class.getResourceAsStream`.

**Bonus option: (not tested)**
And here's a link to [a BB forum post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Resource-file-location-via-URL-e-g-file/m-p/176399#M21937), where a guy shows you can also reference the image using a URL starting with "cod:///".